# About the poor title detection

Tags: support, title

Stack Overflow detects when you input a poor title. For example, it displays something like "That title is too short to be useful. Can you add some more detail?" or "That's not a very good title. Can you add some more unique words to it?" when your title for a question is not adequate.

I am wondering what they use as a criteria (except for the obvious length)?

Comment: This seems more a question for the meta site...

Answer (score 4):

The first message you get when you have a title that contains less than 15 characters. The second message seems to only trigger if your question consists of a single word of 15 characters or more (like the [original revision of this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/15828/khaaaaaaaan-how-to-kill-him). There don't seem to be any other checks, not even whether the words are real.

Having at least 2 words that hit at least 15 characters seems to be sufficient for getting past this. Whether you'll get a list of related questions or "no related questions can be found" depends on your terms. But for example, "SPLongOperation 1" provides 2 results on Stack Overflow.

Separate from this is a simple Regex that checks if the title contains any of the following words:

- Best
- Worst
- Hardest
- You
- Your
- Favorite
- Favourite

If it fires off, then it gives a red warning that the question is subjective and is likely to be closed. This is independent of the above warnings, though.

Comment: There's also the subjective title test

Comment: @YiJiang I thought about that, but that's a different thing. That shows a glaring red error. This only shows a quiet grey one, and is primarily for the Related Questions dropdown. I'll include it, though.