# Are title warnings necessary for high-rep users?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, title

As an extension to [**this post**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82448/about-the-poor-title-detection/82451#82451), are warnings about titles really necessary for high-rep users?

You get this warning just because you have a word like 'you' in your title.

[image: Subjective]

I was wondering if high-rep users could have these disabled. I currently have over 11k on my home site, but I find that in order to avoid these annoying 'warnings' I need to memorize some keywords not to use.

Comment: It is entirely possible for high-rep users to ask bad questions.

Comment: Would this be an example? :P

Comment: Is that a rhetorical question? :)

Comment: Related: [Let users with sufficient reputation use "problem" in titles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108815), with the official (and thoroughly unpopular) answer from Kevin Montrose

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Any message that warns of behaviour shown to be indicative of poor quality questions should be shown to a user regardless of their reputation.

Just because someone has a lot of reputation doesn't mean that they're automatically any good at asking questions. After all, they could have earned all their reputation from answers.

Comment: "After all, they could have earned all their reputation from answers." That makes no sense. If you've managed to earn 20k rep from answers, then clearly you've read a *lot* of questions. You've read lots of good ones and lots of bad ones. The problem with the message is that it has lots of false positives. I asked [this perfectly reasonable question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34466480) a couple days ago, and I have no idea why it triggered this popup.

Comment: @NicolBolas I think that is the real issue, the method of determining subjectivity and other issues is very inaccurate, to say the least.

Answer (score 7):

What is so horrible in this warning? It does not block you from asking, just act as a friendly warning that the question might be closed, so that you won't be surprised if it does.

I don't think it should be disabled.